# Matlab: Find a string in a text file

Tags: matlab

I've searched around, bud didn't find a proper solution. So I ask it again.
There many lines in the `.txt` file. Looks Like this:

```
 PRINT CONTENTS OF SUPERELEMENT yg_bde                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 PRINT OPTION =     3

 HEADER =
            8          55           2          12           6
           13           0          13          11           0
            1           1           0           0           1
            0           0           1          78       14014
            0        1584         166         103        yg_b
         de          1561           0                        
          922         931        1105        1121        1144
         1158        1323        1503           0         989
         1047   110005225           0           0           3
            0                                               0
          419           0           0           0           0
            0           0           0           0

 HEADER SUMMARY:
 NUMBER OF ROWS =    55
 NUMBER OF MATRICES =     2
 NUMBER OF EDGE PLOT LINES =    12
 NUMBER OF DEGREES OF FREEDOM PER NODE =     6
 NUMBER OF DEGREE OF FREEDOM INDICES =    13
 NUMBER OF NODES =    11
 NUMBER OF LOAD VECTORS =     1
 NUMBER OF TRANSFORMATIONS =     0
 BASE FILE NAME= yg_bde
```

I need to locate the `NUMBER OF ROWS =    55`    and get the row number.
I think what need to do is 
1. find and locate the `Number of ROWS`
2. Turn this line into number, so I can get the `55` number

I tried `strfind(file ,string)`, but it can't return the line number, just the index when the file is in one line.

So, How can I Locate the `NUMBER OF ROWS`?

UPDATE:
`whos data`

```
 Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  data      1x1              3094  struct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

**[`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** based approach -

```
%// Import text data as a cell array with each cell holding each row of text data
data = importdata(inputfile,'\n') %// Edit inputfile to the path of your text file

%// Find the row(s) that holds the string 'NUMBER OF ROWS'
row_idx = find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(data,'NUMBER OF ROWS')))

%// Find the number(s) in that/those row(s)
num = arrayfun(@(x) regexp(data{x}, '\d+', 'match'),row_idx)
```

Output I got -

```
row_idx =
    19
num = 
    '55'
```

Now, `num` is a cell array. If you would like to have a numeric array, wrap it with `str2double` -

```
num_array = str2double(num)
```

Note: This also works if you have multiple lines with the string `'NUMBER OF ROWS'`.

---

**Approach #2**

Alternative **[`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html)** based approach that works by reading the text file `line-by-line` -

```
fid = fopen(inputfile); %// Edit inputfile to the path of your text file

tline = fgetl(fid);
num = [];
while ischar(tline)
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'NUMBER OF ROWS'))
        num = [num regexp(tline, '\d+', 'match')]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
num_array = str2double(num)
```

Comment: It reports ` strfind Inputs must be character arrays.` What's the problem?

Comment: @cqcn1991 Could you give `whos data` info?

Comment: @cqcn1991 Could you try with `data = importdata(inputfile,'\n')` instead? For the code to work `data` must come out as a cell array and not as a struct, which is happening at your end.

Comment: Still not working. Can I not turn it into a matrix to locate the string? Just loop through every line of the file?

Comment: @cqcn1991 So, even with `data = importdata(inputfile,'\n')`, `data` is coming out as a struct?

Comment: Exactly, still ` 1x1  10800 struct`.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Check out the alternative approach that was just added?